# How to match results of full text search cross multiple node types in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have following schema (simplified):

```
(:Person)-[:HAS]-(:Item)
```

Created full text index over person name and item name. So search result returns node of 2 types.

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes("ftSearch", "jack ball") YIELD node, score
```

I need to get a list of found items together with items of found person.

```
MATCH (node:Person)-[:HAS]-(i:Item)
MATCH (:Person)-[:HAS]-(node:Item)
```

How to run it in a single query without subqueries?

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Following almost works, the only thing is that in second match "node" is in place of "i" variable and I don't know how to return it.

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes("ftSearch", "jack ball") YIELD node, score
OPTIONAL MATCH (node:Person)-[:HAS]-(i:Item)
OPTIONAL MATCH (:Person)-[:HAS]-(node:Item)
RETURN i
```

Comment: Can you give us an example? How node: can be a Person and an Item? THanks.

Comment: Easy. You can index cross node types.
    CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ftSearch FOR (n:Person|Item) ON EACH [n.name]
This way search by full text index can return both types at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:HAS_ITEM]->(i:item)
WHERE node IN [p,i]
```

or

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:HAS_ITEM]->(i:item)
WHERE p = node OR i = node
```

Comment: These queries would not be performant, as they require scanning all `HAS_ITEM` relationships.

Comment: Thanks! It works. Not sure about performance. Tried it on small data volumes. Approach with subqueries unexpectedly seems to work faster. Need to check on real data volume. Will report later.

Comment: @cybersam what would you recommend? I need to run full text search cross multiple node types, and after I need to join details to filter out results. I've just started with neo4j, have no experience at all.

Comment: I recommend the CALL subquery approach. There is no need to test every `HAS_ITEM` relationship.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [CALL subquery](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/call-subquery/) (available in recent neo4j versions) to conditionally process every `node` returned by the fulltext search (having a high enough `score`) as either a `Person` or `Item`, but not both:

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes("ftSearch", "jack ball") YIELD node, score
WITH node, score
WHERE score > 0.33
CALL {
  WITH node
  WITH node WHERE node:Person
  MATCH (node:Person)-[:HAS]->(other)
  RETURN 'Person' AS lab, other

  UNION

  WITH node
  WITH node WHERE node:Item
  MATCH (other)-[:HAS]->(node:Item)
  RETURN 'Item' AS lab, other
}
RETURN lab, node, COLLECT(other) AS others
```